# Symfony & SonataFormatterBundle - Why is sonata_simple_formatter_type displaying a text field instead of displaying the text formatter field?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to use the SonataFormatterBundle and particularly the sonata_simple_formatter_type.
I followed the exact documentation here : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html

Still, when I want to use it in an admin, it doesn't work as here :
[image: sonata_simple_formatter_type not working]

So, here's my `config.yml` :

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'

sonata_admin:
    title: Artisan du bonheur
    title_logo: favicon.ico
    templates: 
        layout: SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig

sonata_formatter:
default_formatter: richhtml
formatters:
    markdown:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #    - sonata.media.formatter.twig #keep this commented unless you are using media bundle.


    text:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.text
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #    - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    rawhtml:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #    - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    richhtml:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
        #    - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    twig:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
        extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions
```

Here is the `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/layout.html.twig` :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/skins/sonata/style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<script src="{{ asset('bundles/ivoryckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/vendor/markitup-markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/set.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, here is my `RenseignementAdmin` class :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper ->add('title')
                    ->add('content', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array(
                    'format' => 'richhtml'
                    )
                    );
    }
```

By the way, whatever I put instead of richhtml in the `'format'` option, I feel like he doesn't care since I did put things like `bob` `whatever` and he still was displaying a basic text input.

Where did I go wrong ?